# Content shows for a second after button click and then disappears (React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, mapping

I'm trying to display show and hide data on a button click. I'm using axios to fetch the data from a custom API. When I click on the show button, it shows the data however it disappears after a second. Any suggestions ?

Here's the function where I'm fetching the data

```
const Test = () => {
    const [quote, setQuote] = useState([]);
    const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

    const toggleFunction = () =>{
        setToggle(!toggle);
    }
    const getData = async() =>{ 
        try{
            const response = await Axios.get("/reminder");

            if(response && response.data){
                setQuote(response.data);

            }
        }catch(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    }


    useEffect(()=>{
        getData();
    }, [])
```

Here's the snippet where I'm calling the function and looping

```
<div className="divBtn">
                    <button className="styledBtn" type="submit" onClick={toggleFunction}>Show reminders</button>
                </div>
                
            </form>
            {quote.map((single)=>{
                const {id, reminder, time} = single; 
                return(
                    
                    <div key={id}>
                        
                        {toggle ? <LoopReminder id={id} reminder={reminder}/> : null}


                    </div>
                    
                    
                );

            })}
```

Comment: where setToggleReminders() come from?

Comment: Hey sorry, just updated the code. It was a mistake